# Ubuntu 19.10 How To Get Pandoc Making PDF Files?

Tags: command-line, apt, 19.10, pdf, pandoc

Install pandoc:

```
  $ sudo apt install texlive-latex-base pandoc
```

Use pandoc to make pdf from a Markdown file:

```
  $ pandoc file.md -o file.pdf
```

Error message:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1000
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for ecrm1000.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1000

! I can't find file `ecrm1000'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000' failed to make ecrm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm ecrm1000
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for ecrm1000.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf ecrm1000

! I can't find file `ecrm1000'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ecrm1000.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ecrm1000' failed to make ecrm1000.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
Error producing PDF.
! Font T1/cmr/m/n/10=ecrm1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.105 \fontencoding\encodingdefault\selectfont

make: *** [Makefile:4: lifting.pdf] Error 43
```

Comment: Try to install `texlive-fonts-recommended`, using `sudo apt install texlive-fonts-recommended`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install texlive-fonts-recommended as well.

So in order for pandoc to actually create a PDF, you need to do the following:

```
  $ sudo apt install texlive-latex-base pandoc texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Now the above command works (one a valid markdown document named file.md):

```
  $ pandoc file.md -o file.pdf
```

Comment: I installed these and still get: `LaTeX Error: File \`pdftexcmds.sty' not found.` I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, but does that matter?